# Dynamics AX 2012 R2 - swapping out a preview pane dynamically depending on the record selected

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a problem I'm trying to solve and I'm really not sure I'm, A) solving it the correct way, and B) able to do what I want.

I have a List Page that is a basically a summary table (transportation table) that has a record in it for every Sales, Purchase, and Transfer order that we will ship.  With it is a pile of rolled up information and such that's common from the 3 sources.  We use this table on a few list pages and link out to where we need to.  This was all built by someone else, but I'm maintaining some parts around it.

I've gotten a request to have the preview pane on a summary table based list page show the lines from the source order.  So, if a "sales order" is selected in the grid, show the lines in the preview pane for the "sales order" that was selected.  Same for a purchase order and transfer order.

So, my idea, based on pure ignorance and not a ton of experience with Dynamics is that I would just swap out the preview pane based on the source order.  The SalesTableListPagePreviewPane for instance has already been updated to work with linking to this summary table.  So, I wanted to just change the part reference at runtime.

I've managed to get the FormRun on a list page interaction class from the datasource.  I've managed to get a list of the parts via the PartList object.  But, I have no idea how to continue on to actually swap out a part reference.

Am I heading down the correct path?  Is this a completely wrong Dynamics AX pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption, that you can dynamically (run-time) change the parts of the form, is wrong.

Listpages especially are quite static, the only code available through interaction classes. It has the benefit that a listpage can be easily deployed on Sharepoint Enterprise Portal.

You have several options:

1. Use 3 different listpages for each type of transport
2. Use a common relation table with 3 sub-tables (sales, purchase and transfer)

The last option will enable you to do an outer join on the 3 sub-tables. 
The common relation table could be a union view, but I doubt it will perform well.

Comment: An alternative for 2 would be a query based on a [map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb395036.aspx)?

Comment: Not possible, only views and tables allowed.

Comment: Based on your comments, I think #2 would only be doable via a union.  Otherwise, how would I pick the outer joined lines to bind to a grid?

Comment: Proper relations must be defined. I think it is possible, but have not tried it with outer joins.